# Return of a palindrome String it is not the expected one. What is the mechanism behind

Tags: java, recursion, return-value

I am more interested about why does not the return function work. Not about the optimization or my method of thinking.

I have tried a simple program to check recursively if a String is palindrome or not.

```
package palindrom;

public class PalindromString {

  public static boolean isPalindrom(String myText) {

    char f = myText.charAt(0);
    char l = myText.charAt(myText.length() - 1);

    if (f != l) {
        return false;
    }

    else {

        if (myText.length() > 1) {
            isPalindrom(myText.substring(1, myText.length() - 1));

        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return true;

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "cococbc";
    System.out.println(isPalindrom(text));
  }
}
```

For the first step , the program takes that first "c" char and the last one and it compares them, then the function is called again , this time with the "ococb" String. 
The function takes the "o" char and "b" , it compares them , it sees that they are not equal , it goes to the "return false;" statement , and yet it returns true ?

Can you help me with this ? I really want to understand why it behaves this way :|.

Answer (score 2):

> it sees that they are not equal , it goes to the "return false;" statement , and yet it returns true ?

Yes, `isPalindrom("ococb")` returns `false`, but when that recursive call returns, you ignore its return value, and therefore `isPalindrom("cococbc")` returns `true`. You need to return `isPalindrom(myText.substring(1, myText.length() - 1))` in order to fix that.

Besides that issue, you should also change the condition to require `myText.length() is at least 3, otherwise you may pass an empty`String` to the recursive call, since you are removing the first and last characters.

```
    if (myText.length() >= 3) {
        return isPalindrom(myText.substring(1, myText.length() - 1));
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

After you make that change you should remove the final `return true;`, which will no longer be reachable.

You might also consider adding a check for a `null` or empty `String` at the beginning, in order for your method not to throw an exception when called for a `null` or empty `String`.

Comment: Also, a better way of handling the length could be `if(myText.length() == 1) return true;` as the first line of code and the existing `else` part becomes way cleaner then..

Comment: Or you could just turn the logic around: If the Text has 0 or 1 character, it's a palindrom. Otherwise, it's a palindrom if the first and the last character match and the remainder is a palindrom.

Comment: Yes, both suggestions make sense, but I focused on the OP's request: `I am more interested about why does not the return function work. Not about the optimization or my method of thinking`.

Comment: @Eran Regarding :" Yes, isPalindrom("ococb") returns false, but when that recursive call returns, you ignore its return value, and therefore isPalindrom("cococbc") returns true." Could you please tell me why ? Why does it ignore it ?

Comment: @Andreea you have the following logic (forget about the recursion for a minute) : `if (something) {return false;} else {if (somethingElse) {methodCall();} else {return true;}} return true;` - `methodCall()` returns `false`, but you do nothing with that result, and after the outer if statement ends (with no return statement being executed), the final return statement returns `true`.